# This file does not have a program associated with it for performing

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I updated my IE9 from IE8, and after I reboot my machine and try to access my computer drive, I get this error message whenever I try to double click `c:\` drive or other drives:

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing
>   this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed,
>   create an association in the Default Programs control panel

but other than that, everything seems to be working fine. Its very strange; any help?

(I am using Windows 7 32-bit.)

update: [here are the contents of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory`](http://pastebin.com/zWLExrQD).

update 2: [here are the contents of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\folder`](http://pastebin.com/LPAxRvGF).

Comment: Could you run `reg query HKCR\Drive /s | clip` in Command Prompt and paste the result here? Also, does this happen with file folders, or only drives?

Comment: it happends with folders and drives too

Comment: can you elobrate more how do you want me to run query hkcr ?

Comment: @Abu: 1) I see. In that case, `reg query HKCR\Directory /s | clip` would be more useful... 2) Start -> Accessories -> Command Prompt; then copy/paste the `reg ...` thing and press Enter. Because of `| clip`, the results will automatically go to clipboard and can be pasted.

Comment: @Abu: Could you run the command for `HKCR\Folder` too? Apparently I got `Directory` and `Folder` mixed up - sorry about that :(

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Just finished solving this exact same issue by comparing notes with the .reg files available for download here:

> http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-asso-fixes-for-windows-7/

If you're paranoid like me just go through each entry until you find the differences and fix those accordingly.

Comment: `.reg` files are text files. You could just `diff` the two files to see where the differences are as merge at your discretion.